# Change the question to include more viewpoints from other anime and manga productions

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

Based on [my question about censorship in Pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29534/are-there-censored-or-discarded-pokemon-creatures-and-what-are-the-motives-behin), I'm thinking in if I can post another question asking *basically* the same, but with another anime *i.e. Yu-Gi-Oh!*

> *I'm really a fan of Yu-Gi-Oh! since its beginning, but, I avoided ask about Yu-Gi-Oh! censorship because I did think that Anime & Manga community would not take it serious (I was a little paranoic on that I must confess **maybe for The Abridged Series** episodes...)*

But, I really don't know if that behavior would be considered as abuse or discouraged or duplicate questions *therefore, may bring downvotes or would be closed*; so, I'm wondering.

- Should and *can* I make sepatared questions about censhorship with different anime and manga creations?
- Should or *must* I edit my current question for make it more comprehensive i.e *where the accepted answer should be the one which provides more info in different anime and manga creations?*

Comment: I actually think this question is more interesting about Yugioh than about Pokemon, since Yugioh was aimed at an older audience and had human-looking monsters

Comment: @Torisuda, I'll post the question about Yu-Gi-Oh! then :) Thanks _(or if someone will do it first, I wont see problems with that)_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Ask 2 different questions for 2 differents topics

The right behavior would be to make two separate questions, one for *Yu-Gi-Oh!* and one for *Pokemon*, as the only thing that would link the two questions is the fact that they are both animes. Those are two differents questions, with their respective universes and their respective stories.

From the help center on "[How to ask a good question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" :

> Be specific
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

Having the same question over two different universes **is not** a duplicate if it stays in the range on the series because their answers are completely different

#### You can ask a question about Yi-Gi-Oh!

The tag [yu-gi-oh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh) does exist and has some constistent answers on it, there is no reason why you shouldn't make a question about this anime/manga as long as they respect the rules of the Stack Exchange. Don't be afraid of closes and downvotes : if your question is relevant and is well formated, there is no reason why anyone would downvote you, and **we must and we will** do what it takes to let this question open (if it fits the general rules of course).

#### Your question does not need to be more specific

> I'm interested in knowing if there are censored or discarded Pokemon creatures, and if so, what are the motives behind it. Has Satoshi Tajiri published information about it?<sup>2</sup>
>
> <sup>2</sup> With the last statement I mean if Satoshi Tajiri approved or rejected the idea/fact of censoring his creations, or if he worked in the censored version, etc.

This particular sentence and its annotation are great, the context you introducted before, while not necessary, is still okay. The fact your question got upvoted 6 times with no downvotes reflects what the Stack Exchange's community feels about it : it is good. You explain us in clear details what you are looking for, and ask for potential official publication. I don't this why this should be reworked.

If you have a conflict between different answers, you can then edit your post to explain what kind of answer you would accept, therefore showing why you choosed an answer over another one. Bear in mind that I don't think a lot of people here would be offended of not having his/her answer accepted if they are given the reason why.